# 'arr' was not declared in this scope when declaring arr in default constructor

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, class-members

I am new to C++. I am trying to implement a *stack*. I am declaring an `arr` named variable inside the *default constructor*.

But when I compile my code I get an error saying

```
'arr' was not declared in this scope
```

My code:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;

class Stack
{

private:
    int top = -1;
    int n = 100;

public:
    Stack()
    {
        int arr[n]; // 100 element stack
    }

    void push(int element)//push element to the top of the stack
    {
        if (isFull() == false)
        {
            // push element
            top += 1; //increment top
            arr[top] = element;
        }
        else cout << "\nStack is full! Can't push element\n";
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if (isEmpty() == false)
        {
            top -= 1;//decrement top
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if (top == -1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    bool isFull()
    {
        if (top == n - 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    int peek(int position)// item at specific location
    {
        if (position > top)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid position\n";
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return arr[position];
        }
    }

    int count()// number of items
    {
        return top + 1;
    }

    void change(int position, int value) // change item at specific location
    {
        if (position > top)
        {
            cout << "\nInvalid postion\n";
        }
        else
        {
            arr[position] = value;
        }
    }

    void display() // display elements stored
    {
        if (isEmpty() == false)
        {
            cout << endl;
            for (int i = 0; i < top; i++)
            {
                cout << arr[i] << endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << endl << "Stack is empty! No elements to display" << endl;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Stack st;

    cout << endl;
    cout << st.isEmpty();

    st.push(10);

    cout << endl;
    cout << st.isEmpty();

    st.display();

    return 0;
}
```

My error:

```
stack.cpp: In member function 'void Stack::push(int)':
stack.cpp:28:4: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
   28 |    arr[top] = element;
      |    ^~~
stack.cpp: In member function 'int Stack::peek(int)':
stack.cpp:68:11: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
   68 |    return arr[position];
      |           ^~~
stack.cpp: In member function 'void Stack::change(int, int)':
stack.cpp:85:4: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
   85 |    arr[position] = value;
      |    ^~~
stack.cpp: In member function 'void Stack::display()':
stack.cpp:96:11: error: 'arr' was not declared in this scope
   96 |     cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
      |           ^~~
```

I do not understand why this is happening.

Shouldn't be the `arr` accessable to all member functions?

Comment: `arr` is no different from `n` and `top`. You're doing the right thing there.

Comment: @cigien please clarify.  ```int arr[n]``` is in ```Stack()``` which means it's local to ```Stack()```, no?

Comment: `int arr[n]; // 100 element stack` is a local variable that exists only inside the constructor. It is also a VLA which is not legal in standard c++.

Comment: Yes. It's why the compiler is saying you can't use it in the other member functions.

Comment: “Shouldn't be the arr accessable to all member functions?” - *why* should it be so? Make sure to support assertions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The

```
int arr[n]; // 100 element stack
```

is a local variable that exists only inside the constructor(scope). The other members will not know about this array and that is the reason for the error.

Move the array declaration to the private section and `n` should be known at compile time

```
class Stack
{

private:
   int top = -1;
   static constexpr int n = 100;  // n as static constexpr
   int arr[n]{ 0 };               // move `arr` here and optionally initlize to `0`

public:
   Stack() = default;
   // ... rest of the code

};
```

As a side note, when you do array operations (i.e. like in `push` member) do a bound check to the passed `position`.

Comment: Small note on `int arr[n]{0};` this doesn't initialise to `0` because a `0` is passed in, it initialises to `0` because it's default initialised like that. Writing `int arr[n] { 2 };` doesn't initialise elements to 2, it only initialises the first to 2 and the rest to 0.

Comment: @Tas Yes, You are right. I wanted to initialize the array ele. to `0`'s. And it [could have been simply `int arr[n]{ };`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_brace-enclosed_lists).

Answer (score 0):

This is because arr is not a class member, but only a local variable defined in constructor. It vanishes together with constructor scope end.

Start your class like this:

```
class Stack
{
  int top = -1;
  static int const n = 100;
  int arr[n]; // 100 element stack                                                                                                                    

public:
  Stack() {}
  // ...
}
```